# Can I analyze Project (.csproj) and Solution (.sln) relationships with Roslyn?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have just started to use Roslyn, because I would like to develop some static analysis pet projects focused on generating dependency graphs (the output would be .dot files to be compiled to .pdf with Graphviz).

I can see the potential to analyze the code in a per-file basis, but I need the following operations (more or less):

1. Given a `solution.sln` file, find all `project.csproj` files referenced by it;
2. Given a `project.csproj` file, find all `sourcecode.cs` files referenced by it;
3. Parse these files with Roslyn, as usual;
4. Have a solutionwide parse tree or something, where namespaces spanning more than one project would have its classes grouped together.

Specifically, my question is: can I perform operations 1, 2 and 4 with Roslyn, or should I use other tools / techniques instead? Any suggestion?

P.S. I see there is a [`VisualStudioWorkspace`](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/) but I couldn't figure out what I have to do to use it, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; this is certainly possible.

`VisualStudioWorkspace` is used within VS itself; you should only use that from within a VS addin to access the current solution.

To load a solution yourself, use `MSBuildWorkspace`.
You will then want to merge symbols from the `Compilation`s for each project.

Comment: I ended up using `MSBuildWorkspace`, it worked fine! Of course now I'll have to experiment with it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you're in VS, you should _not_ use MSBuildWorkspace. Both derive from just "Workspace" so for a tool like this you can probably just make all your code use the base type, and you can use either if you have a VS extension or a command line tool.